# 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any>'

Tags: typescript

Starting typescript 4.7.4, the `PrefixedRecord` in my `Flatten` type is now broken and can't be indexed by the keys provided.

Can someone suggest a quick workaround or another way to fix this?

Appreciate the help !

```js
export declare type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;
declare type StringKeysOf<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;
declare type PrefixedRecord<Prefix extends string, Obj extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [Key in StringKeysOf<Obj> as `${Prefix}.${Key}`]: Obj[Key];
};
declare type NonObjectKeysOf<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<any> ? K : T[K] extends object ? never : K;
}[keyof T];
declare type ObjectKeysOf<Obj> = Exclude<keyof Obj, NonObjectKeysOf<Obj>>;
export declare type Flatten<T, K extends StringKeysOf<T> = StringKeysOf<T>> = UnionToIntersection<K extends ObjectKeysOf<T> ? PrefixedRecord<K, T[K]> : {
    [k in K]: T[K];
}>;
```

[image]

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDjAnmbAVQDsBLCYgFQgEliZgoBnFGc4gHkID44BeOAApCcUA2IImcdMVxwA-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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `T[K]` extends `Record<string, any>` so it will be happy to be used in `PrefixedRecord`.

```js
export declare type Flatten<T, K extends StringKeysOf<T> = StringKeysOf<T>> = UnionToIntersection<K extends ObjectKeysOf<T> ? T[K] extends Record<string, any> ? PrefixedRecord<K, T[K]> : never : {
    [k in K]: T[K];
}>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDjAnmbAVQDsBLCYgFQgEliZgoBnFGc4gHkID44BeOAApCcUA2IImcdMVxwA-EIDWALjiEAlP14A3CKQRw1xYDsZaxwCVMGq4pYgDNGcGlr679hxTSNwTZlAA3ACwAFBIaJjYeARwAMowUA4A5gDSwLhMAPKOHJS8AgCiIEnoyDAcSpkQjnCUADRwTEmp3KERKBhYOPjYAApYjqQgwAgASijQCByDwMMgoqVWks2txClN2QBGAFZL4quTyNMcLckbTTK43IVwAN7hcM9wANoZcg4J6+mZOXk7Xa8dBSAAGABJ7nMFgBfAB0kI+MNBAF01ID3pkUR0YR1It0Yn04AA5CiA1gff75O6PMIvN5pezEODVXC1epo+rvFEHFZSACCUCg6FwHGuvEUjLUlG5vOscAge1YCn8phcajSONerPZlGx4Xx0V6cXJFUpuQ4gLuJTQAFckFUanVAU1ScRTTBzQC9rcOqBILBEF0jbFsAAxDAwcT5JqMyzyxIXX5ZC0FfjfJNe6l3Ejsah0BjMVjsDhx5byj1ZtOKGVpHnxo5TKAzc6pK6yCVwaEjMbHU5pJq1lG8YxqqB+Wn07VMuB16XcnHtcL+6Dwe648JAA)

I'm sure there's a way to re-write the whole thing to make it more elegant, but this should work fine.

Comment: This can indeed do the trick, thanks!
I will consider re-writing the whole think to make it more elegant though. Appreciate the help!